# Xml Writer: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml

I have the exact same routine to write data to a Xml file without any problems. Here I am trying to write a class instance data and on the first line I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Xml.dll

In the [**Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t5yhhk(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that the `writer` is closed. How can I "open" it?

```
// stuff
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path + "\\" + this.Name);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", this.Id.ToString()); // error pops here
writer.WriteAttributeString("Description", this.Description);
// other stuff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to write an *attribute* but you haven't written an *element* yet.
So what you basically need to do is: create an element prior to writing an attribute:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("book");
writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", this.Id.ToString()); // ID becomes an attribute of "book"
```

What the documentation says is that the writer will be closed, when an `InvalidOperationException` is raised. By default it's open.

**Edit:**

Have another look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx) :-)

> When you use the XmlWriter methods to output XML, the elements and
>   attributes will not be written **until you call the Close method**. For
>   example, if you are using the XmlWriter to populate an XmlDocument,
>   until you close the XmlWriter, you will not be able to observe the
>   written elements and attributes in the target document.

So if you want the contents to be written to file, you'll have to flush or close the writer. You can do this via an explicit invocation (`writer.Close()`) or - maybe a bit nicer - with an `using`-statement, which disposes and closes the writer for you:

```
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path + "\\" + this.Name))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("book");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", this.Id.ToString());
    // even more elements etc.

} // .Close() is called implicitly for you
```

**Edit2:**

The resulting XML is written into a single line, because writing whitespace would just *waste* resources. XML can be written into a single line validly.
But if you want the XML to be indented nicely and be human-readable, you'll have to specify that via [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path + "\\" + this.Name, settings))
{
    // other code...
```

Comment: Sweet Thanks :) This fixed my issue however all the data are on the same line. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Well I edited my comment for that :D I figured it out that I needed to `close()` but I will use your `using` =) Thanks again. And do you know why all the data are on one line within the file?

Comment: Have a look again ;)